# How to increase width of textarea without modifying div?

Tags: javascript, css, yui-pure-css

How to resize textarea in following case using Pure CSS, without damaging whole structure of table:

**Heading**:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-8">
<label class="boldText">Nmbr</label>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
<label class="boldText">ques</label>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
<label class="boldText">comments</label>
</div>
```

**Row1**:

Bla Bla

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
One more Bla
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
One More Bla
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
<textarea class="normal" style="height: 75px; width:300px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;" name="commento" id="commento"></textarea>
</div>
```

The problem is that Textarea is remained as width applied using "pure-u-md-1-5 div" class.

When i try to increase width, like style="width:400px", it does not increase width of textarea.

If i try to increase width of its div then text area jumps to next row. If i adjust by decreasing pixel like from 400px to 490 or 495 then also , when i try to zoom pages, text area shifts to next row.

How to increase width of textarea by not modifying div?

Comment: did you try increasing the 'cols' property? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_cols.asp

Comment: Yes. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

apply style `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;`

Comment: It takes textarea to left most part of screen. But as in code. Textbox is in 4th row. It does not work

Comment: @fatherazrael you have to have at least 1 parent container with style `position:relative;`, I make it for example using `div {position:relative;}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `pure-u-` class to the textarea. To use the full width of the column would be like this:

```
<textarea class="normal pure-u-1" style="height: 75px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;" name="commento" id="commento"></textarea>
```

Or if you want a slight margin on the right you could use `class="normal pure-u-23-24"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you could try not using the div, but just displaying the textarea using the classes:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
One more Bla
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
One More Bla
</div>
<textarea  class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5" style="word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;" name="commento" id="commento"></textarea>
```

However I get the impression that you want to be able to dynamically adjust the size of the text area larger than pure-u-md-1-5 size allows.  In that case you may be better off using a popup or something similar, and just putting a button you can click to open it and edit the text area?